# Name of set $\sum_{i=1}^nx_i\leq c, x_i\geq 0 \quad \forall i$.

Tags: geometry, convex-optimization

Fix $n$ as a positive integer. Fix $c>0$. The following set $A$ is called a "simplex":
$$\mbox{$A = \left\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n: \sum_{i=1}^n x_i=c, x_i\geq 0 \quad\forall i \in \{1, ..., n\}\right\}$}$$
Is there a corresponding name for the following related set?
$$ \mbox{$B = \left\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n: \sum_{i=1}^nx_i\leq c, x_i\geq 0 \quad\forall i \in \{1, ..., n\}\right\}$}$$
I want to call set $B$ a "subsimplex" but I wonder if there are alternative established names.  I am using such sets in the context of convex optimization.

Comment: Why would you call it a sub-simplex? It's not a simplex itself.

Comment: Because sub means "under" and it is the set of nonnegative vectors bounded above by the simplex. It can also be viewed as the projection of the $(n+1)$-dimensional simplex onto the first $n$ dimensions.

Comment: @DionelJaime : I suppose I could also just call it a "pyramid."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's another simplex! ([By definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex), a simplex is a $k$-dimensional polytope that is the convex hull of its $k+1$ vertices.) If we use the names $A_n$ and $B_n$ to indicate the dimension of the ambient space, then $A_n$ is an $(n-1)$-dimensional simplex and $B_n$ is an $n$-dimensional simplex. Indeed, the map from $B_n$ to $A_{n+1}$ given by
$$
(x_1,\dots,x_n) \mapsto \biggl(x_1,\dots,x_n,c-\sum_{i=i}^n x_i\biggr)
$$
is an isomorphism. (Try this map out when $n=1$ and $n=2$ to gain some intuition.)

Comment: Thanks, this seems similar to my comment to the Dionel Jaime comment. However why would you call it a simplex?  It is also isomorphic to the unit interval $[0,1]$ and also the open interval $(0,1)$ (meaning it can be measurably mapped 1-1 with a measurable inverse) so isomorphisms do not seem to be a key aspect here. Perhaps "linear isomorphism" but then why would a linearly deformed simplex also be called a simplex?

Comment: I was thinking primarily of the probability simplex (for $c=1$) so my working defintion of "simplex" was basically sets of the type $A$. However on wikipedia I see a more general definition that allows convex combinations of any linearly independent vectors together with the vector 0, so my set $B$ could be indeed called a "simplex" under that generalized definition, though it would not be a probability simplex.

Comment: One reason I think it's accurate to call this a simplex (even though topologically it's also a ball, etc.) is that its polygonal faces of all dimensions are all simplexes as well. As "polyhedra", simplices are characterized by all of their faces being simplices as well (the $n$-dimensional simplex is the cone on an $(n-1)$-dimensional simplex).

Comment: I will upvote and select this as "best answer." However you may want to edit or comment to include the working definition of simplex that you are using. I think a question like this does not fully make sense without it (my implicit limitation of the definition to sets of the type $A$ was not correct).  Wikipedia currently has a definition that you may be assuming.  Perhaps another definition would be a set that is a linear isomorphism from a set of type $A$ in any dimension. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex

Comment: Thanks for your edit, and thanks again for the answer!